# "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/: 404 Not Found" Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I start in Angular 5, I want to display the list of Cities from a JAX-RS API, then I get the following error :

> Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/: 404 Not Found

Here you will find my files with which I work :

***ville.service.ts***

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Ville } from '../models/ville.model';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class VilleService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

    private userUrl = '/api/';

  public getVilles() {
    return this.http.get<Ville[]>(this.userUrl);
  }

  public deleteVille(ville) {
    return this.http.delete(this.userUrl + "/"+ ville.idVille);
  }

  public createVille(ville) {
    return this.http.post<Ville>(this.userUrl, ville);
  }

}
```

***proxy.config.json***

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/QuickDep/Compagne",
      "secure": false
    }
  }
```

in ***package.json***

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/QuickDep",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Comment: private userUrl = '/api/';

Comment: remove the last /

Comment: Again it's the same